# Sort by memory usage in docker stats

Tags: docker

Is there a way to display the docker stats sorted by memory usage of the containers?

I am using the following command to display the container with their names and I want to sort the result by memory usage.

```
docker stats --format "table {{.Name}}\t{{.Container}}\t{{.CPUPerc}}\t{{.MemUsage}}"
```

The unsorted result is the following.

```
NAME                                                                   CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT
kafka3.interactive.8a38c338742464ffb04d6f23fc6485391318d103            0d68b7fd49a0        1.39%               359.5 MiB / 4.833 GiB
kafka2.interactive.8a38c338742464ffb04d6f23fc6485391318d103            7e5541b0b883        1.22%               309.4 MiB / 4.833 GiB
kafka1.interactive.8a38c338742464ffb04d6f23fc6485391318d103            dff07c6d639c        0.68%               267.4 MiB / 4.833 GiB
service2.interactive.8a38c338742464ffb04d6f23fc6485391318d103          0f20a7e75823        0.06%               617.8 MiB / 4.833 GiB
consulakms.interactive.8a38c338742464ffb04d6f23fc6485391318d103        b5972262194d        3.82%               10.32 MiB / 4.833 GiB
service1.interactive.8a38c338742464ffb04d6f23fc6485391318d103          be56185a37bf        0.09%               596.3 MiB / 4.833 GiB
consumer1.interactive.8a38c338742464ffb04d6f23fc6485391318d103         05145beb209c        0.06%               574.6 MiB / 4.833 GiB
consul1.interactive.8a38c338742464ffb04d6f23fc6485391318d103           3298a8159064        0.67%               10.57 MiB / 4.833 GiB
consul3.interactive.8a38c338742464ffb04d6f23fc6485391318d103           4a1bbbd131ad        3.12%               9.664 MiB / 4.833 GiB
zookeeper2.interactive.8a38c338742464ffb04d6f23fc6485391318d103        040f00b4bbc7        0.09%               42.45 MiB / 4.833 GiB
consulbootstrap.interactive.8a38c338742464ffb04d6f23fc6485391318d103   45268a11f2f4        3.62%               11.46 MiB / 4.833 GiB
zookeeper3.interactive.8a38c338742464ffb04d6f23fc6485391318d103        331772b27079        0.12%               51.27 MiB / 4.833 GiB
consul2.interactive.8a38c338742464ffb04d6f23fc6485391318d103           77b63171e6b5        1.07%               12.59 MiB / 4.833 GiB
zookeeper1.interactive.8a38c338742464ffb04d6f23fc6485391318d103        c5ad82730598        0.08%               43.17 MiB / 4.833 GiB
service3.interactive.8a38c338742464ffb04d6f23fc6485391318d103          610da86c6949        3.79%               546.7 MiB / 4.833 GiB
squid.interactive.8a38c338742464ffb04d6f23fc6485391318d103             928ddbb197fa        0.01%               144.2 MiB / 4.833 GiB
```

Comment: see https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/11398 and https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/18277, there seems to be some way

Answer (score 78, accepted):

To sort by `Mem Usage` field you can use the following command:

GNU/Linux:

`docker stats --no-stream --format "table {{.Name}}\t{{.Container}}\t{{.CPUPerc}}\t{{.MemUsage}}" | sort -k 4 -h`

MacOS:

`docker stats --no-stream --format "table {{.Name}}\t{{.Container}}\t{{.CPUPerc}}\t{{.MemUsage}}\t{{.M‌​emPerc}}" | sort -k 9 -n`

Check this link to view all available options to `--format` option of `docker stats`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/#formatting

Comment: I want to get the memory usage sorted

Comment: I already know how to display the memory, my problem is about sorting the result

Comment: My new edit based on the new info you added should fix your problem. Please, validate the answer if it was helpful for you.

Comment: It does not work. I have tested with the following command `docker stats --no-stream --format 'table {{.Name}}\t{{.Container}}\t{{.CPUPerc}}\t{{.MemUsage}}\t{{.MemPerc}}' | sort -k 5 -h`. By the way, I cannot test it on MacOs as the flag `-h` is not supported in `sort`.

Comment: I just figured out the mistake. The command `docker stats --no-stream --format "table {{.Name}}\t{{.Container}}\t{{.CPUPerc}}\t{{.MemUsage}}\t{{.MemPerc}}" | sort -k 9 -n` is working.

Answer (score 7):

```
docker stats --no-stream --format "table {{.Name}}\t{{.Container}}\t{{.MemUsage}}" | sort -k 3 -h
```

Commands sort only by memory

Comment: Thanks! And make it `sort -k 3 -h -r` to reverse the sort, showing the highest memory at top (and incidentally the headers at bottom, but I can live with that).

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your locale's decimal seperator is a DOT. If it is different sorting won't work.

That's why I use this command (Linux), note the `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8`:

```
docker stats --no-stream --format "table {{.Name}}\t{{.Container}}\t{{.CPUPerc}}\t{{.MemUsage}}" | LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 sort -k 4 -h
```

Answer (score 5):

I didn't like the delay that using the `watch` method introduced (way slower than using `docker stats` directly), so I wrote this:

```
python - << EOF
import subprocess
import re
def getmemperc (value):
    try:
        return float(re.split('\s+', value)[6][:-1])
    except:
        return 0
proc = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'docker','stats'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
arr = []    
for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline,''):
    line = line.rstrip().decode()
    if (line.startswith('\x1b[2J\x1b[H')):
        if arr != []:
            print(arr.pop(0))
            arr = sorted(arr, key=lambda x: getmemperc(x), reverse=True)
            for a in arr:
                print(a)
        arr = []
    arr.append(line)
EOF
```

No additional delay when compared to `docker stats`.

Comment: Best answer by far. 1) The only one that correctly handles memory usages of Mbs and Gbs, and correctly puts the Gbs before the Mbs; 2) doesn't have to stop streaming and 3) as fast as vanilla `docker stats`. The only thing I don't like: it uses `sudo`. Would it work without it?

Comment: @DeltaIV
If you're able to call 'docker stats' with your user without sudo, then it works without it here too.

Comment: I would like to generalize this code a bit more, such as, for example, sort on something else than memory percentage. Could you explain what the code does more in detail?

Comment: @DeltaIV the selection happens in def getmemperc.
"re.split('\s+', value)" split the lines by spaces. "[6]" make it select the 7th element of each line of docker stats (which is memory %). "[:-1]" removes the % sign from that. float() turns what is left into an float. "return 0" is a fallback in case the details are not printed, which is usually caused by docker being slow at the moment.
To sort by something that has MB/GB you would also need to add some function to convert that into Bytes for proper sort. I'll try to look into it.

Comment: thanks for the clarification! I'll try to modify it to sort on something else, and report on results. Rather than continuing the discussion in the comments, what if I ask a new question? I'll just add the question link here once I'm done.

Answer (score 4):

Building off of the previous answers I created the following function and put in in my alias file.

Every second it captures the dockers stats and then generates 4 tables sorted descending by CPU %, MEM USAGE, NET I/O, and BLOCK I/O.

Also, this does maintain the table headers :-)

```
function dks() { 
    watch -n 1 'STATS=$(docker stats --no-stream --format "table {{.Name}}\t{{.Container}}\t{{.CPUPerc}}\t{{.MemUsage}}\t{{.NetIO}}\t{{.BlockIO}}"); echo "$STATS" | (read -r; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; sort -k3hr) | head; echo; echo "$STATS" | (read -r; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; sort -k4hr) | head; echo; echo "$STATS" | (read -r; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; sort -k7hr) | head; echo; echo "$STATS" | (read -r; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; sort -k10hr) | head;'; 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't maintain the table headers for me.

Answer (score 3):

Get top 10 container sorted by memory usage

```bash
docker stats --no-stream | sort -k 4 -h -r | head -10
```

Live mode

```
watch -n 1 'docker stats --no-stream | sort -k 4 -h -r | head -10'
```