# Get docker container resource usage in CPU's desc

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker

I'm trying to get the resource usage stats of running containers in docker. The command docker stats --format `"table {{.Container}}\t{{.CPUPerc}}\t{{.MemUsage}}"` gives the result but is there a way to list these results in CPU usages' desc order?

Thanks for all advice in advance.

Comment: there was a PR on that subject, but I am not aware  of any solution at the moment https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/11398

Comment: more or less duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43930011/sort-by-memory-usage-in-docker-stats ?