# How to sort or order results docker ps --format?

Tags: docker

I haven't found any way to order my results when using `docker ps`

In my case I want to order by .Ports

```
docker ps -a --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Ports}}"
```

How do I order the result?

Comment: if you pipe and sort it? or have a look at Andy'answer from Docker Inspect Template Magic from Adrian Mouat http://container-solutions.com/docker-inspect-template-magic/ I guess you look for a docker only solution

Comment: I don't think you can do anything golang template specific to do this. You need to build your own stuff for this. What may work is hitting the API and using `jq` to sort results and display. But not sure how easy that would be

Comment: from http://webgeodatavore.com/jq-json-manipulation-command-line-with-geojson.html I see `Sort only value, not the object (return array)` and `jq '[.features[].properties.pop_est] | sort' countries.geojson` so I guess this is possible with jq (I do not have a docke ravailable at the moment, I will test later)

Comment: and `jq -R .|jq -sr 'sort_by(length)[]'` sort by length from https://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/comments/3z9jff/jq_examples/

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43930011/sort-by-memory-usage-in-docker-stats for a similar basic `docker command | sort` and ther is an issue on that subject, see https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31062

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Format and Order *docker ps*

**List containers**

```
docker ps
```

**Synopsis**

```
docker ps [--format="TEMPLATE"]

--format="TEMPLATE"
  Pretty-print containers using a Go template.
  Valid placeholders:
     .ID - Container ID
     .Image - Image ID
     .Command - Quoted command
     .CreatedAt - Time when the container was created.
     .RunningFor - Elapsed time since the container was started.
     .Ports - Exposed ports.
     .Status - Container status.
     .Size - Container disk size.
     .Names - Container names.
     .Labels - All labels assigned to the container.
     .Label - Value of a specific label for this container. For example {{.Label "com.docker.swarm.cpu"}}
     .Mounts - Names of the volumes mounted in this container.
```

**Display containers with their commands**

```
docker ps --format "{{.ID}}: {{.Command}}"
```

**Display containers with their labels in a table**

```
docker ps --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Labels}}"
```

**Display containers with their node label in a table**

```
docker ps --format 'table {{.ID}}\t{{(.Label "com.docker.swarm.node")}}'
```

Comment: what is `"$REPLY"` ?

Comment: Read is a bash builtin that reads from stdin and stores the value in a variable. If you don't provide a name for the variable it uses REPLY. https://ss64.com/bash/read.html

Comment: This answer didn't contain the sorting part at all, and just copied it from the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49973096/3266847), currently second highest voted, without attribution?

Comment: @BenjaminW. So great that you found the answer I copied from, which I was unaware. I copied in Nov 2018, answered in Sep 2017.

Comment: I am using the fish shell, the command docker ps --format 'table {{.ID}}\t{{(.Label "com.docker.swarm.node")}}' is invalid. Is there any way to execute it in the fish shell?

Comment: This does NOT sort.  Consider concise and capable [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46173298/how-to-sort-or-order-results-docker-ps-format/49973096#49973096).

Answer (score 37):

If it's enough to simply sort by output column, you can use the following:

```
 docker ps -a --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Ports}}" | (read -r; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; sort -k 3 )
```

I also added a code for  skipping the table headers and sorting only ps output data.

Comment: For those wondering, the final statement of `sort -k 3` indicates that the Docker container results will be sorted ascending by the third column of the format template.  So in this example, the container list will be sorted by the respective container's exposed ports.

Answer (score 10):

I built a docker ps pretty print function that can be put into your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file that works somewhat like an alias for `docker ps` (with color output).  *[@art-rock-guitar-superhero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2588010/art-rock-guitar-superhero)* suggestions shows how to sort, but I've included this answer since typing the `--format` options and piping into a `sort` every time is a bit tedious.

```
function docker () {
    if [[ "$@" == "ps -p" ]]; then
        command docker ps --all --format "{{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Ports}}\t{{.Status}}" \
            | (echo -e "CONTAINER_ID\tNAMES\tIMAGE\tPORTS\tSTATUS" && cat) \
            | awk '{printf "\033[1;32m%s\t\033[01;38;5;95;38;5;196m%s\t\033[00m\033[1;34m%s\t\033[01;90m%s %s %s %s %s %s %s\033[00m\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10;}' \
            | column -s$'\t' -t \
            | awk 'NR<2{print $0;next}{print $0 | "sort --key=2"}'
    else
        command docker "$@"
    fi
}
```

usage: `$ docker ps -p`.

**EDIT:** *I added suggestions from the comments from [@BrianVosburgh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566345/brian-vosburgh).  Also, I kept forgetting to type `-p` so I switched the flag for this function to be `-a`, which is my regular usage of `docker ps`.*

Comment: Nice function. : ) But I think there is an extraneous backslash in the 'awk' pattern: `...196m\%s\t...` should read `...196m%s\t...`.

Comment: Also, you could sort the table with something like this: `docker ps -p | awk 'NR<2{print $0;next}{print $0 | "sort --key=2"}'`

Comment: @BrianVosburgh, yes, thanks, I removed the extraneous backslash.  I'm not sure why, but it had no impact on the output.  Also, the extra stuff to sort by second column (key) of name, is a nice suggestion as well, and so I've updated the original answer with your sort command.

Comment: You cannot sort on the status, as this field contains `Up 2 days`, `Shutdown about a day ago` or whatever. It just works if all the containers were created on the same moment and they have all the same status. I create another answer that describes how to generate the ISO date from the `Status` value and sort on it.

Comment: @Ser the proposed solution sorts by `Name` only, it's not configurable to sort by Status intentionally to make it a simple use for general purpose.

Comment: Yes. It just makes more sense to me to sort on the only date we have. And my answer does it, it's not trivial but it's working great. And sorry I missread this thread, I though you were sorting too on Status, which is not the case

Comment: You can sort by any column - you just need to do the `sort` (with field-separator=tab) before the `column` strips the tabs out. And, while you're at it, why go to all the bother of sorting excluding the headers? Why not just sort before you add the headers? I'm now using a variant of this function that looks like this:

`docker <stuff> | sort -t $'\t' --key=4 | echo-cat-magic | awk to add colours | column`

Answer (score 0):

### Prettify Docker ps output

- open terminal
- run export command to export **Env** Variable
- you can customise according to desired output needed

```sh
export FORMAT="ID\t{{.ID}}\nNAME\t{{.Names}}\nIMAGE\t{{.Image}}\nPORTS\t{{.Ports}}\nCOMMAND\t{{.Command}}\nCREATED\t{{.CreatedAt}}\nSTATUS\t{{.Status}}\n"
```

- run command
  **docker ps --format="$FORMAT"**

**e.g Output**

```sh
khizerrehan@khizerrehans-MacBook-Pro ~ % docker ps --format="$FORMAT"
ID  9bfbfe65dce1
NAME    happy_joliot
IMAGE   nginx:alpine
PORTS   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp
COMMAND "/docker-entrypoint.…"
CREATED 2021-09-05 00:20:45 +0500 PKT
STATUS  Up 4 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not strictly related to the OP question, but if you want to sort on the Status date, you need to support date that are relatives : `Up 2 days ago`, `Shutdown about a day ago` etc.
This bash script generates an ISO date from the Status value, then we sort on the ISO date and finally we remove the ISO date.

```sh
# 1- List all containers 
#    As I'm working with swarm, you may want to adapt to your docker cli usage. 
#    Use "docker ps --format '{{ json . }}" to see available fields
# 2- add a column that translate "Shutdown 2 days ago" into ISO date. Also supports "Shutdown about a day ago". 
# 3- sort on that date
# 4- remove the ISO date and add colors
# 5- make the output readable
docker stack ps --format '{{ .CurrentState }}\t{{ .Name }}\t{{.Node}}\t{{.Image}}' demo \
  | awk -F'\t' '{system("date --rfc-3339=seconds -u -d \"$(printf \"" $1 "\" | cut -d \" \" -f2- | sed \"s/about//g\") \" | tr -d \"\n\"") ; printf "\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5;}' \
  | sort -r \
  | awk -F'\t' '{ printf "\033[32m%s\033[39m\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", $2, $3, $4, $5, $6;}' \
  | column -o " " -t -s $'\t'
```

It generates something like that :
[image: ordered containers by date]