# Docker ps -a sort by date

Tags: docker

docker ps sorts by time, but the most recent docker instance is at the very top. This means if you started very many instances you have to scroll all the way to the top to see them. How do we output "docker ps -a" in reverse order, so that the most recent instance is printed at the bottom?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pipe the output to `tac`[1] like:

```
docker ps -a | tac
```

[1] From `man tac`: tac - concatenate and print files in reverse

Answer (score 10):

Latest created container:

```
docker ps -a -l
```

Latest 5 created containers:

```
docker ps -a -n 5
```

As far as I know ordering is not possible but maybe you  don't really need it...

Answer (score 5):

It's enough to get what you want.

```
$ docker ps -a --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.CreatedAt}}" | (read -r; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; sort -k 3  -r )
```

See also

- [How to sort or order results docker ps --format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46173298/how-to-sort-or-order-results-docker-ps-format)